# mongorestore --drop slow on small db

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a real Mongo instance for my integration tests. On every test, I call `mongorestore my_db_state --drop` because I need a clean db to start the next test.

On my tiny db (with only one test user account) it takes 180 ms to run `mongorestore my_db_state` (without `--drop`) and `455 ms` with `--drop`.

I don't understand why it's taking so long to drop the db, but how can I speed this up?

I may have a bunch of different connections on the mongo server because I never close them on my Flask server, but they probably should be closed after the test is over...just not sure if this is an issue to care about.

Is there a faster way to restore a snapshot to its original state for testing purposes?

Comment: Can you please provide more information, such as how big your tiny database is (in number of rows and actual data size if possible)?